# Can't Make Post Request with Swift

Tags: swift, post, parameters, http-post, httprequest

I tried to make a post request with swift, but it always shows me an error. I just copy the post request that my chrome did(via the developer tool).

```
func postRequest(){

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://blich.iscool.co.il/tabid/2117/language/he-IL/Default.aspx/")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "__VIEWSTATE=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&nn$ctr7919$TimeTableView$ClassesList=1&dnn$ctr7919$TimeTableView$MainControl$WeekShift=0&dnn$ctr7919$TimeTableView$ControlId=8"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            println("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        println("response = \(response)")

        let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("responseString = \(responseString)")
    }
    task.resume()



        }
```

the result is:

```
response = <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7ffc90f054a0> { URL: http://blich.iscool.co.il/Default.aspx?tabid=2117&error=The+state+information+is+invalid+for+this+page+and+might+be+corrupted.&content=0 } { status code: 200, headers {
"Cache-Control" = private;
"Content-Encoding" = gzip;
"Content-Length" = 2875;
"Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Thu, 07 May 2015 07:41:32 GMT";
Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
"Set-Cookie" = "DotNetNukeAnonymous=aaab9a64-e579-43f8-a83e-d4ed7c221f02; expires=Thu, 07-May-2015 08:01:32 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly, language=he-IL; path=/; HttpOnly";
Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
"X-AspNet-Version" = "2.0.50727";
"X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
```

When I just read the file without make post request it shows me the right thing, but when I make a post request it wrong.

How can I fix it? I want that this website will show to me the data on the right table that i choose in my application.
http://blich.iscool.co.il/tabid/2117/language/he-IL/Default.aspx/

this is the current code:  error has been fixed-but **still do nothing**

```
func postRequest(){
    SRWebClient.POST("http://blich.iscool.co.il/tabid/2117/language/he-IL/Default.aspx/").data(["__EVENTTARGET":"dnn$ctr7919$TimeTableView$btnChangesTable","__EVENTARGUMENT":"","__LASTFOCUS":"","__VIEWSTATE":"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","__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR":"CA0B0334","dnn$ctr7919$TimeTableView$ClassesList":"1","dnn$ctr7919$TimeTableView$ControlId":"","ScrollTop":"","__dnnVariable":""]).send({(response:AnyObject!, status:Int) -> Void in
            //this is success part
            println(response)
            }, failure:{(error:NSError!) -> Void in
                //this is failure part
                println(error)
        })
}
```

Comment: why not using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this [SRWebClient](https://github.com/sraj/Swift-SRWebClient). You Just need to add [this swift file](https://github.com/sraj/Swift-SRWebClient/blob/master/SRWebClient/SRWebClient.swift) to your project and save it as `SRWebClient.swift`.

Then when ever you are posting, you can use this code.

```
 SRWebClient.POST("http://blich.iscool.co.il/tabid/2117/language/he-IL/Default.aspx/")
                .data(["yourFieldName":"yourValueForTheField"])
                .send({(response:AnyObject!, status:Int) -> Void in
                       //this is success part
                        println(response)
                    }, failure:{(error:NSError!) -> Void in
                       //this is failure part 
                        println(error)
                    })
```

This is the simple and easiest way. Try it and if any problems, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: It says to me under SRWebClient.Post: "Use of unresolved identifier 'SRWebClient'", any idea? Thanks

Comment: have u added the [this] (https://github.com/sraj/Swift-SRWebClient/blob/master/SRWebClient/SRWebClient.swift) to your project ? And names it as SRWebClient.swift ?

Comment: ok now it is working find, No error but nothing changes, When I click on for example the rightest button in the top(״מערכת שינויים״) chrome tells me the requests so i copied them to my application, run - but nothing changed. I will edit the post that you will see my code(and sorry that the website is all in Hebrew:))

Comment: Hi Shaik, did you understand my problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you tu use the library "Alamofire" for the HTTP requests. Here's the link : https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

It makes it so easy :

```
    request(.POST, url, parameters: parameters).responseJSON()
    {
         (request, response, data, error) in
         if (data != nil)
         {
           // Do what you want
         }
    }
```

Then, feel free to parse JSON with SwiftyJSON : https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON, or whatever you want to do.

EDIT: For the parameters, you need to create a dictionary like this :

```
    let parameter = [
       "key1": "value1",
       "key2": "value2"
    ]
```

But everything is explained in the "Usage" section of the documentation

Comment: still it doesn't work, I think I sent the paramaters wrong, any idea?

Comment: Yes I know but still something goes wrong, I explained the problem to details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30100209/post-request-with-swift-doesnt-work